# spring boot requestMapping @RequestMapping(value = "/{userId:\\d+}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)

Tags: java, spring-boot, request-mapping

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{userId:\\d+}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public void delete(@PathVariable Long userId) {
        try{
            this.authorService.delete(userId);
        }catch(Exception e){
            throw new RuntimeException("delete error");
        }
    }
```

Anybody know what url should I match for this definition "/{userId:\d+}", could you give me an example, like "/userid=1", is this right?

I guess that definition like this "/{userId:\d+}" , using regular expression in url to make sure it pass a number parameter.I am not sure about that , if anybody knows it please give me a link for further learning, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that expression maps `/1` for example, all the digits.

> The syntax {varName:regex} declares a URI variable with a regular expressions with the syntax {varName:regex} — e.g. given URL "/spring-web-3.0.5 .jar", the below method extracts the name, version, and file extension:

```
@GetMapping("/{name:[a-z-]+}-{version:\\d\\.\\d\\.\\d}{ext:\\.[a-z]+}")
public void handle(@PathVariable String version, @PathVariable String ext) {
    // ...
}
```

Check the complete doc [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-uri-templates)

Answer (score 0):

It will match any digit. For example,

`/1`, `/11`, `/123`.

`/{userId:\\d+}` ===> map one or more digits after `/` to variable userId.
Regular expression for one or more digits is `\d+`, but since you are using it as a string you need to escape it using another `\`.